# My JQuery function wont activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, django-templates

I'm trying to get my background image to move with my mouse as it moves upon the #titleheader class objects. The page renders fine but the functionality doesn't activate. I'm working in Django. I've added the first (top of the page) #titleheader object from the base template which extends into a home template which contains the other #titleheader object. I've compiled both templates into what chrome would see when rendering the page below. I suspect suspect something is wrong in the line: `$(this.target).css('background-position', event.pageX + 'px ' + event.pageY + 'px');` but I'm unable to figure out what to change in my code.

My index page is as follows:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> #landing-content {
  background-size: 110%;
  height: 110%;
  width: 110%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
        } </style>

        <title>Home Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/courses/css/layout.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".titleheader").mousemove(function(event){
                    $(this.target).css('background-position', event.pageX + 'px ' + event.pageY + 'px');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body id="landing-content" background="/static/courses/images/back7.jpg">
  <section class="site-container slider">
    <article class="glass down">
      <div class="titleheader" style="width:100%;height:80px;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:100%;left:0;right:0;background-color:rgba(229,240,247,0.7);border-width:1px;z-index:0;border-bottom-style:solid;border-color:#f0fafb;">
    <a href="/" class="titleheaderimg">
        <img src="/static/courses/images/tz_blue2.png" alt="G" class="titleheaderimg" style="z-index:100;opacity:1;align-self:center;position:relative;top:9%;left:1%;">
    </a>
      </div>
    </article>

<div style="height:100px;">
    <p>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="centrediv" style="width:720px;position:absolute;top:26%;bottom:45%;left:0%;right:0;margin:auto;background-color:rgba(229,240,247,0.7);border-radius:20px;border-color:#f0fafb;border-width:1px;">
    <h2 style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;opacity:1">Hi,<span><br><br></span>We are a <span><a href="/courses/team/">XYZ based team</a></span> that works with educators to improve their efficiency using state-of-the-art language processing technology.<span></span>
        <br><span><a href="/courses/product/">Know more.</a></span></h2>
</div>

<div class="centrediv" style="position:absolute;top:86%;bottom:0;left:47%;right:0;margin:auto;">
    <h3><a href="/courses/contact/">Contact us.</a></h3>
</div>

  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**:

The code is updated now and there is no error in console, pycharm, chrome dev tools, or anywhere. Still the background doesn't move! Can someone help me with this issue please? Thanks!

Comment: I disabled all my extensions. I'm not getting errors in the devtools. But the Jquery functionality still doesn't activate. Is something wrong with my <script>?

Comment: Just checked both. Still no luck. :(

Comment: Right. I changed that to ".titleheader" - still nothing. Which debugger do you recommend here? 
And why isn't this post getting higher visibility? Its been a couple of hours and only 9 views?? Dont get it!

Answer (score 0):

According to the MDN on mouseevent.pageX,

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

You said you're using Chrome, and Chrome *is* listed as the *only* browser supporting the pageX and pageY accessors, but it might be worthwhile to consider another way. `MouseEvent.clientX` is supported on all modern browsers - could you get that to work?

Also, I've had trouble with the `$(this)` selector - I prefer to use a fully qualified element selector when the method will only be dealing with one element anyways. Might be worth trying.

Good luck!